# Fixed aspect ratio View

Tags: android, view, aspect-ratio, viewgroup

How would I go implementing a fixed aspect ratio `View`? I'd like to have items with 1:1 aspect ratio in a `GridView`. I think it's better to subclass the children than the `GridView`?

EDIT: I assume this needs to be done programmatically, that's no problem. Also, I don't want to limit the size, only the aspect ratio.

Comment: Jesper Borgstrup has created a helper class to use with onMeasure: http://www.buzzingandroid.com/2012/11/easy-measuring-of-custom-views-with-specific-aspect-ratio/

Comment: Google has provided the Percent Support Library: https://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/features.html?linkId=18501246#percent

Comment: @c0nstruct0r Classes PercentFrameLayout and PercentRelativeLayout from Support Library were deprecated in 26.0.0. For now you should consider using ConstraintLayout to size your views in predefined aspect ratio. See my answer below.

Comment: This is a JQuery plugin that helps with aspect ratio:
https://github.com/eissasoubhi/aspectratio.js

Answer (score 85, accepted):

I implemented FixedAspectRatioFrameLayout, so I can reuse it and have any hosted view be with fixed aspect ratio:

```
public class FixedAspectRatioFrameLayout extends FrameLayout
{
    private int mAspectRatioWidth;
    private int mAspectRatioHeight;

    public FixedAspectRatioFrameLayout(Context context)
    {
        super(context);
    }

    public FixedAspectRatioFrameLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)
    {
        super(context, attrs);

        init(context, attrs);
    }

    public FixedAspectRatioFrameLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle)
    {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);

        init(context, attrs);
    }

    private void init(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)
    {
        TypedArray a = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.FixedAspectRatioFrameLayout);

        mAspectRatioWidth = a.getInt(R.styleable.FixedAspectRatioFrameLayout_aspectRatioWidth, 4);
        mAspectRatioHeight = a.getInt(R.styleable.FixedAspectRatioFrameLayout_aspectRatioHeight, 3);

        a.recycle();
    }
    // **overrides**

    @Override protected void onMeasure (int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec)
    {
        int originalWidth = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);

        int originalHeight = MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec);

        int calculatedHeight = originalWidth * mAspectRatioHeight / mAspectRatioWidth;

        int finalWidth, finalHeight;

        if (calculatedHeight > originalHeight)
        {
            finalWidth = originalHeight * mAspectRatioWidth / mAspectRatioHeight; 
            finalHeight = originalHeight;
        }
        else
        {
            finalWidth = originalWidth;
            finalHeight = calculatedHeight;
        }

        super.onMeasure(
                MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(finalWidth, MeasureSpec.EXACTLY), 
                MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(finalHeight, MeasureSpec.EXACTLY));
    }
}
```

Comment: The Init method should start with a lower-case. Java convention.

Comment: I just implemented something along these lines, based on `PreviewFrameLayout` from the Camera AOSP app. However, I am noticing that gravity no longer seems to be honored -- in cases where the height is constrained, all the extra whitespace seems to be at the bottom even with `Gravity.CENTER` or `Gravity.BOTTOM`, for example. Have you seen this? If so, did you happen to come up with a solution? Thanks!

Comment: @CommonsWare put the `FixedAspectRatioFrameLayout` inside a `RelativeLayout` and add `android:layout_centerInParent="true"` to the `FixedAspectRatioFrameLayout`

Comment: @Oliv: Yeah, I wound up doing something along those lines: https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-layouts

Comment: Paste this into a res/values/attrs.xml: ` <declare-styleable name="FixedAspectRatioFrameLayout">
  <attr name="aspectRatioWidth" format="integer" />
  <attr name="aspectRatioHeight" format="integer" />
 </declare-styleable>
`

Comment: @tar - you need to wrap <declare-styleable ...> in <resources></resources>

Comment: Implement this class in a new file, and then use it in a layout instead of a regular FrameLayout. Google "implementing custom views in Android" if you need the basics. But I would suggest the solution below of using googles own percent support library (which didn't exist when I wrote this solution).

Answer (score 39):

To not use third-party solution and considering the fact that both PercentFrameLayout and PercentRelativeLayout were deprecated in 26.0.0, I'd suggest you to consider using ConstraintLayout as a root layout for your grid items.

Your `item_grid.xml` might look like:

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageview_item"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="H,1:1" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

As a result you get something like this:

[image: Fixed ratio sized grid items]

Comment: Thanks, this works like a charm, however, Android Studio complains that "H,1:1" is an invalid float. If you set app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="1.0" it works the same way but without the warning.

Answer (score 38):

For new users, here's a better non-code solution :

A new support library called [**Percent Support Library**](http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/features.html#percent)  is available in *Android SDK v22* (MinAPI is *7* me thinks, not sure) :

> src : [android-developers.blogspot.in](http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2015/10/android-support-library-231.html)
>
> *The Percent Support Library provides percentage based dimensions and margins and, new to this release, the ability to set a custom aspect ratio via app:aspectRatio. By setting only a single width or height and using aspectRatio, the PercentFrameLayout or PercentRelativeLayout will automatically adjust the other dimension so that the layout uses a set aspect ratio.*

To include add this to your *build.gradle* :

```
compile 'com.android.support:percent:23.1.1'
```

Now wrap your view (the one that needs to be square) with a [`PercentRelativeLayout`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/percent/PercentRelativeLayout.html) / [`PercentFrameLayout`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/percent/PercentFrameLayout.html) :

```
<android.support.percent.PercentRelativeLayout
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content">
     <ImageView
         app:layout_aspectRatio="100%"
         app:layout_widthPercent="100%"/>
 </android.support.percent.PercentRelativeLayout>
```

You can see an example [here](https://github.com/JulienGenoud/android-percent-support-lib-sample).

Comment: While PercentRelativeLayout is good for some use cases, it doesn't work with scroll views pre M and is way more complex since it supports child sizing. If you just need a fixed aspect ratio view then accepted answer is just best.

Comment: The percent library is deprecated as of 26-rc1 in favor of `ConstraintLayout`... Which isn't very related to one another.

Answer (score 9):

I recently made a helper class for this very problem and wrote a [blog post about it](http://www.buzzingandroid.com/2012/11/easy-measuring-of-custom-views-with-specific-aspect-ratio/).

The meat of the code is as follows:

```
/**
 * Measure with a specific aspect ratio<br />
 * <br />
 * @param widthMeasureSpec The width <tt>MeasureSpec</tt> passed in your <tt>View.onMeasure()</tt> method
 * @param heightMeasureSpec The height <tt>MeasureSpec</tt> passed in your <tt>View.onMeasure()</tt> method
 * @param aspectRatio The aspect ratio to calculate measurements in respect to 
 */
public void measure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec, double aspectRatio) {
    int widthMode = MeasureSpec.getMode( widthMeasureSpec );
    int widthSize = widthMode == MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED ? Integer.MAX_VALUE : MeasureSpec.getSize( widthMeasureSpec );
    int heightMode = MeasureSpec.getMode( heightMeasureSpec );
    int heightSize = heightMode == MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED ? Integer.MAX_VALUE : MeasureSpec.getSize( heightMeasureSpec );

    if ( heightMode == MeasureSpec.EXACTLY && widthMode == MeasureSpec.EXACTLY ) {
        /* 
         * Possibility 1: Both width and height fixed
         */
        measuredWidth = widthSize;
        measuredHeight = heightSize;

    } else if ( heightMode == MeasureSpec.EXACTLY ) {
        /*
         * Possibility 2: Width dynamic, height fixed
         */
        measuredWidth = (int) Math.min( widthSize, heightSize * aspectRatio );
        measuredHeight = (int) (measuredWidth / aspectRatio);

    } else if ( widthMode == MeasureSpec.EXACTLY ) {
        /*
         * Possibility 3: Width fixed, height dynamic
         */
        measuredHeight = (int) Math.min( heightSize, widthSize / aspectRatio );
        measuredWidth = (int) (measuredHeight * aspectRatio);

    } else {
        /* 
         * Possibility 4: Both width and height dynamic
         */
        if ( widthSize > heightSize * aspectRatio ) {
            measuredHeight = heightSize;
            measuredWidth = (int)( measuredHeight * aspectRatio );
        } else {
            measuredWidth = widthSize;
            measuredHeight = (int) (measuredWidth / aspectRatio);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: A FixedAspectRatioFrameLayout based on this code: https://github.com/triposo/barone/blob/master/src/com/triposo/barone/FixedAspectRatioFrameLayout.java

Comment: I am not sure if you have to do all these things, just call the baseclass to onMeasure to do the heavylifting and fix the measuredheight from the measuredwidth * aspect ratio before returning.

Comment: Depends on what you want to do. I think you are describing possibility 3 (width fixed, height dynamic) in the code above.

Answer (score 5):

I created a layout library using [TalL](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1154443/tall)'s answer. Feel free to use it.

[RatioLayouts](https://github.com/riteshakya037/RatioLayouts)

## Installation

Add this to the top of the file

```
repositories {
    maven {
        url  "http://dl.bintray.com/riteshakya037/maven" 
    }
}


dependencies {
    compile 'com.ritesh:ratiolayout:1.0.0'
}
```

## Usage

Define 'app' namespace on root view in your layout

```
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
```

Include this library in your layout

```
<com.ritesh.ratiolayout.RatioRelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/activity_main_ratio_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:fixed_attribute="WIDTH" // Fix one side of the layout 
        app:horizontal_ratio="2" // ratio of 2:3
        app:vertical_ratio="3">
```

## Update

With introduction of [ConstraintLayout](https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout/index.html) you don't have to write either a single line of code or use third-parties or rely on `PercentFrameLayout` which were deprecated in 26.0.0.

Here's the example of how to keep 1:1 aspect ratio for your layout using `ConstraintLayout`:

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
        android:background="@android:color/black"
        app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="H,1:1"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 4):

I've used and liked Jake Wharton's implementation of `ImageView` (should go similarly for other views), others might enjoy it too:

[AspectRatioImageView.java](https://gist.github.com/JakeWharton/2856179) - *ImageView that respects an aspect ratio applied to a specific measurement*

Nice thing it's styleable in xml already.

Answer (score 4):

You may find third-party libraries. Instead of using them, use constraint layout.
Below code sets the aspect ratio of ImageView as 16:9 regardless of the screen size and orientation.

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/mat3"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="H,16:9"/>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

`app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="H,16:9"`. Here, height is set with respect to the width of the layout.

[image: Portrait activity]

[image: Landscape activity]

For your question, set `android:layout_width="match_parent"` and use `app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="H,1:1"` in your view.

Answer (score 3):

Simply override `onSizeChanged` and calculate ratio there.

Formula for aspect ratio is:

```
newHeight =  original_height / original_width x new_width
```

this would give you something like that:

```
 @Override
protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
    super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);

    //3:5 ratio
    float RATIO = 5/3;
    setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams((int)RATIO * w, w));

}
```

hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

The ExoPlayer from Google comes with an [`AspectRatioFrameLayout`](https://exoplayer.dev/doc/reference/com/google/android/exoplayer2/ui/AspectRatioFrameLayout.html) that you use like this:

```
<com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.AspectRatioFrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:resize_mode="fixed_width">
    <!-- https://exoplayer.dev/doc/reference/com/google/android/exoplayer2/ui/AspectRatioFrameLayout.html#RESIZE_MODE_FIXED_WIDTH -->

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.AspectRatioFrameLayout>
```

Then you must set the aspect ratio programmatically:

```
aspectRatioFrameLayout.setAspectRatio(16f/9f)
```

Note that you can also set the resize mode programmatically with [`setResizeMode`](https://exoplayer.dev/doc/reference/com/google/android/exoplayer2/ui/AspectRatioFrameLayout.html#setResizeMode-int-).

---

Since you are obviously not going to grab the whole ExoPlayer library for this single class, you can *simply copy-paste the file from GitHub* to your project (it's open source):

https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/blob/release-v2/library/ui/src/main/java/com/google/android/exoplayer2/ui/AspectRatioFrameLayout.java

Don't forget to grab the attribute `resize_mode` too:

https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/blob/release-v2/library/ui/src/main/res/values/attrs.xml#L18-L25

```
<attr name="resize_mode" format="enum">
  <enum name="fit" value="0"/>
  <enum name="fixed_width" value="1"/>
  <enum name="fixed_height" value="2"/>
  <enum name="fill" value="3"/>
  <enum name="zoom" value="4"/>
</attr>
```

Answer (score 1):

I have used in this way.

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout

```
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/imageView_home_one"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="0dp"
                        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="H,4:3"
                        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_5sdp"
                        android:visibility="gone"
                        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints" />
                </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```