# How to apply aspect ratio from material design specs on a view?

Tags: android, android-layout, material-design, android-cardview, aspect-ratio

I am designing an `CardView` for my app with a rich media header.

I try to make something like this:

[image: Rich media header from google material design specification]

According to google material design specification, the picture should have a 16:9 aspect ratio:

[image: Google rich media header specification]

So, my question, how to achieve this (Code or XML) ?

If I use a defined size, it will not be a real 16:9 aspect ratio and I will have to handle many resource files for all screen sizes and orientations.

Else, I did not succeed to set a size by code because in `onBindViewHolder(...)`, `getWidth()` on my view return 0.

Any idea ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way would be to use [`PercentRelativeLayout`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/percent/PercentRelativeLayout.html) as the parent `ViewGroup`.  Then you can set the follow XML attributes on your `ImageView`

```
 app:layout_widthPercent="100%"
 app:layout_aspectRatio="178%"
```

Another option is to write your own custom `ImageView` and override `onMeasure()` to ensure that the view ends up with a 16:9 ratio.  [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10772572/868492%20This) answer shows you how to do that.

Comment: `PercentRelativeLayout` sounds good, but it doesn't work...

I got `Error:(15) No resource identifier found for attribute 'layout_aspectRatio'`

(I have put the dependency `compile 'com.android.support:percent:23.0.1'` in my `build.gradle`)

Comment: Make sure you add the `app` xml namespace in your layout `xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"`

Comment: I have the `app` xml namespace in my layout... Moreover, Android Studio warn me with: `'layout_height' should be defined`

Comment: Yeah those are just lint errors.  Your app should actually build with it.

Comment: I succeed to use the `PercentRelativeLayout` with some attributes like `layout_heightPercent` but `layout_aspectRatio` still does not exist...

Comment: Ok, got it: [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33415492/how-to-use-layout-aspectratio-in-the-percentrelativelayout)

Comment: Note: use `app:layout_widthPercent="100%"` and `app:layout_aspectRatio="178%"` to obtain 16:9 aspect ratio.

Answer (score 11):

Now with both `PercentFrameLayout` and `PercentRelativeLayout` being deprecated in 26.0.0, you should consider using of [ConstraintLayout](https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout/index.html) to build out your cards.

Here is the xml snippet for your case:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    style="@style/CardView.Light"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp">

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/media_image"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            app:srcCompat="@android:color/darker_gray"
            app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="H,16:9"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/supporting_text"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="spread_inside" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/supporting_text"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            android:text="Greyhound divisively hello coldly wonderfully marginally far upon excluding."
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1"
            android:textColor="#DE000000"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/media_image"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent" />

    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

You can check out other card implementations via ConstraintLayout [here](http://eugenebrusov.com/cardview-with-constraintlayout/). All of them were built in compliance with [Material design guidelines](https://material.io/guidelines/components/cards.html#cards-content-blocks).

Comment: I know this is old...but isn't it redundant to use CardView if you can achieve the same look and feel with a ConstraintLayout alone?