# How to use layout_aspectRatio in the PercentRelativeLayout?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-constraintlayout, android-percentrelativelayout

I try to achieve a 16:9 aspect ratio on a view with the [`PercentRelativeLayout`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/percent/PercentRelativeLayout.html).

So I have put this line in my build.gradle file: `compile 'com.android.support:design:23.0.1'`

I use this layout:

```
<android.support.percent.PercentRelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        app:layout_aspectRatio="178%"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"/>

</android.support.percent.PercentRelativeLayout>
```

Problems:

- Android Studio warn me with: `'layout_height' should be defined` for the `ImageView`.
- When I run my project I got : `Error:(15) No resource identifier found for attribute 'layout_aspectRatio'`.

So what's wrong ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Now with both PercentFrameLayout and PercentRelativeLayout being deprecated in 26.0.0, you can start using [ConstraintLayout](https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout/index.html).

This [blog article](http://eugenebrusov.com/using-constraintlayout-to-set-your-imageview-in-169-ratio/) explains how to achieve a 16:9 aspect ratio for ImageView using ConstraintLayout, but it can be applied to any view.

Answer (score 14):

With the correct dependency you still had the warn

> 'layout_height' should be defined

I used  android:layout_height="0dp" or android:layout_width="0dp" to avoid it.

```
           <View
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            app:layout_aspectRatio="75%"
            app:layout_widthPercent="100%"
             />
```

you can even use android:layout_height="wrap_content" in case of the content will be bigger that the layout_aspectRatio

Answer (score 13):

It appears you're using the wrong dependency in an attempt to include the [Percent Support Library](https://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/features.html#percent).

The correct one (and latest version) is:

```
com.android.support:percent:23.1.0
```

In other words, the declared dependency should look like this in your gradle file:

```
compile 'com.android.support:percent:23.1.0'
```

Answer (score 3):

There is a g+ post here: https://plus.google.com/+AndroidDevelopers/posts/ZQS29a5yroK that explains how to use this in some depth.

In the comments there's also a discussion about the layout_width/height warning. A Lint filter will be added in a future Android Studio version, but until then you can add a `<!-- suppress AndroidDomInspection -->` to suppress the warning, or just ignore it.